# Could not find class: org.junit.tests.AllTests - OSX

Tags: java, macos, junit

I'm having a little trouble getting started with JUnit tests. This should be pretty basic. I downloaded junit-4.8.2.jar from JUnit.org and placed it in my home directory.

If I try to test my setup in a TCSH terminal with the following command:

```
java -cp ~/junit-4.8.2.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.junit.tests.AllTests
```

I receive the following output

```
JUnit version 4.8.2
Could not find class: org.junit.tests.AllTests

Time: 0.003

OK (0 tests)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the documentation say you need to pass exactly "org.junit.tests.AllTests" as the second argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out: [the junit faq](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#overview_4) specifically this item, bolding mine:

> Test the installation by running the sample tests distributed with JUnit. **Note that the sample tests are located in the installation directory directly, not the junit.jar file.** Therefore, make sure that the JUnit installation directory is on your CLASSPATH. Then simply type:
>
> java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.junit.tests.AllTests

If you only downloaded the jar you can't run the sample tests.  You need to get the src package and follow the instructions for that.

Answer (score 1):

This was posted by unixking - 
Get the latest version of JUnit from http://sourceforge.net/projects/junit/files/junit/4.10/

Unzip junit4.10.zip at C:\MyDev\lib, so we have C:\MyDev\lib\junit4.10

In the command prompt, run the following commands

```
: the home is where i work best
set MY_HOME=C:/MyDev

: place to find the junit jar files
set JUNIT_HOME=%MY_HOME%/lib/junit4.10

: find the junit jar files as well as other classes that one intends to use
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JUNIT_HOME%;%JUNIT_HOME%/junit-4.10.jar

: this is where my jdk is
set JAVA_HOME=%MY_HOME%/tool/jdk1.6.0_24

: run sample tests (sitting in any folder)
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.junit.tests.AllTests
```